# Iphone Push Notification Wrong Device Token

Tags: php, iphone, notifications, push

**Finally,I found out the sandbox tokens,which were mixed with the production tokens,and I update the code,receive the error response from apple,when post a sandbox token to apple,the next tokens all failed....While the push msg was "$payload['aps'] = array('content-available' => 1); ",apple will push the msg ,but the device will not show this msg,when I find the wrong one,I delete it,and retest.**

There is an amusing problem of apple push notification service:
when I generate a post notification for my device and send to apple's server,for a while,my device will receive the notification.
But if I first post a notification by a wrong devicetoken,then post a right notification to my device,my device will be responseless,just like the push notification was eaten by apple?

What wrong with this?

I use php code for push service,here is the most important part:

```
$payload['aps'] = array('content-available' => 1);
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        foreach ($line as $deviceToken) {
            break;
        }

        print_r($deviceToken);
        $apnsMessage = chr(1) . $time . $time . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        $ret = fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
        if ($ret !== strlen($apnsMessage)) {
            echo "push error";
        }

        ob_flush();
        flush();

        $read = array($apns);
        $null = null;
        $changedStreams = stream_select($read, $null, $null, 0, 100000);//wait for 0.1s

        if ($changedStreams === false) {    
            echo "Error: Unabled to wait for a stream availability";
        } elseif ($changedStreams > 0) {
            print "can't receive any notification behind this token";

            $responseBinary = fread($apns, 6);
            if ($responseBinary !== false || strlen($responseBinary) == 6) {

                $response = unpack('Ccommand/Cstatus_code/Nidentifier', $responseBinary);
                print_r($response);
            }
        } else {
            //update the success push status in database
        }

        print "<br>";
    }
```

I dont know what's wrong with this,and I have also add feedback service in another php,and get none wrong token from apple,Because I have many devicetoken in my database,I cant find which one of them is wrong.

Someone help me,forgive my poor english

Comment: Is the "wrong deviceToken" has a correct format? How "long" will apple "ban" you? (several notifications or 1 minutes?)

Comment: the wrong devicetoken is sandbox token when i test application,when i post a sandbox token to apple,the next tokens all failed.

Comment: if all following tokens failed, how can you get "unbanned"? so that you can send a token (wrong or correct) again to Apple?

Comment: Are you sending the sandbox token to the sandbox server btw?

Comment: If there is a wrong token, **"can't receive any notification behind this token"** will appear,then I delete the banned one,retest until no error meg showing.     <BR/>I test sandbox tokens and distribution tokens in a same database,so many new user can't receive push notification at all

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `$apns` is implemented in this way

```
$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2,STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
```

you should check the $errorString to find out the error.

or try to close the socket for each message and see if there is any difference

```
fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
socket_close($apns);
fclose($apns);
```

Comment: I have these also,I just post parts of my codes.connection and other all are ok